# Creating a mosaic out of rotated raster with gdal_translate

Tags: python, gdal

I have a number of images (the amount does not really matter) which are georeferenced with a correct transform ( since they show correct position and rotation in qgis).

But when I try to use gdal_translate the function struggles to output a correct mosaic if the images are rotated more than 2 degrees from the North.

It seems like the function has problems creating correct sized windows for each rotated image. I am wondering if anyone has stumbled upon this problem before and has a solution?

Comment: `gdalwarp` them first (can use VRT format) then mosaic

Comment: It actually did work to make a mosaic just with gdalwarp. That was the missing peace thanks!